# Using arrays for pulling and filling simple data in JS, which is more efficient or "correct"

Tags: javascript

This a completely noob question.  I'm learning Javascript from StackSkills, there is no blog or community.  We have gotten through functions, arrays if/else, case, etc.  We had a project to work on that counted calories, added them up for a week and determined if you ate too much, just enough, or not enough.  The course seems to be designed to force you to look things up, etc, which obviously make sense, but there is no one to ask questions to.

To count the calories per day, my function has an array full with the seven days listed as strings.  The function calls the days from the array, calls the calories function, and totals the calories to a var.  The answer presented by the course uses a series of function calls to do the same.  I know both of these are so simple, there is no real difference in computer usage, but at a higher level (ie. being used in a real website), is one way more practical or more 'correct' than the other?  Or are both really just super simple examples to learn the function in the code, and this problem would not be solved this way IRL?  Example of code below.

My solution

```
function getTotalCalores() {
  //array for days of week (0-6)
  var weekDays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];
  var totalCalories = 0
  var daycount = 0
  //while statement that calls inputCaloriesByDay() with argument from array
  while (daycount <= 6) {
    day = weekDays[daycount];
    totalCalories += inputCaloriesByDay(day)
    daycount += 1;
  }
  return totalCalories
}
```

Example solution

```
function getTotalCalories() {
return inputCaloriesByDay('Monday') +
inputCaloriesByDay('Tuesday') +
inputCaloriesByDay('Wednesday') +....
```

etc...

Comment: I don't think it matters that much in this case. Your code is a bit more verbose because of the loop (by the way, a `for` loop is probably better than `while` just because it saves you two lines)  but it ultimately does the same. The example solution works fine - it's more copy/paste but it's only seven items and they are well defined and won't be changing (days of the week). So, whether you call `inputCaloriesByDay` in a loop with (always) 7 iterations or "hardcode" the (always) seven calls, it doesn't matter here.

Comment: Some programmers would just do soemthing like `moment.weekdays().map(e=>inputCaloriesByDay(e)).reduce((a,c)=>a+c,0)` really not carrying about performance or readability :)

Comment: You can also put weekDays out side the function so it will treat like a closure and var weekDays only initialize once and doesn't matter how many time we call it

Comment: @GauravKandpal that's kind of what I did in my answer...

Comment: @CodyＧ code readability is what make the difference between a junior and a senior developer. The *example* provided by StackSkills, even if not perfect, is more readable both of your solution and the below answer.
Furthermore, if the requirement changes some sort of unnecessary abstraction could be counter-productive. Take a look at this interesting post by Dan Abramov: https://overreacted.io/goodbye-clean-code/

Comment: Your black and white statements are strongly opinionated and I don't know whether or not to be offended.

Comment: This type of question (in which your code is already correct but may not be idiomatic) is well suited for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the solution, skip to the bottom. If you're interested in how I got there, read on...

---

Personally, I'd suggest using some of the fancier `Array.prototype`/`Object.prototype` methods to slice up your data instead of `while` loops....like so:

Here's your code:

```
function getTotalCalores() {
  //array for days of week (0-6)
  var weekDays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];
  var totalCalories = 0
  var daycount = 0
  //while statement that calls inputCaloriesByDay() with argument from array
  while (daycount <= 6) {
    day = weekDays[daycount];
    totalCalories += inputCaloriesByDay(day)
    daycount += 1;
  }
  return totalCalories
}
```

The first thing I'd do is clean up those [magic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string), like so:

```
var DAY = {
  MONDAY: 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY: 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY: 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY: 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY: 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY: 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY: 'SUNDAY',
};

function getTotalCalores() {
  //array for days of week (0-6)
  var weekDays = [DAY.MONDAY, DAY.TUESDAY, DAY.WEDESDAY, DAY.THURSDAY, DAY.FRIDAY, DAY.SATURDAY, DAY.SUNDAY];
  var totalCalories = 0
  var daycount = 0
  //while statement that calls inputCaloriesByDay() with argument from array
  while (daycount <= 6) {
    day = weekDays[daycount];
    totalCalories += inputCaloriesByDay(day)
    daycount += 1;
  }
  return totalCalories
}
```

The only problem is now, that if we ever decide that we want to ignore a particular week day, we would have to edit the `DAY` variable and the `weekDays` variable, which is a PITA. So let's clean that up using `Object.values`

```
const DAY = {
  MONDAY: 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY: 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY: 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY: 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY: 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY: 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY: 'SUNDAY',
};

function getTotalCalores() {
  //array for days of week (0-6)
  var weekDays = Object.values(DAY);
  var totalCalories = 0
  var daycount = 0
  //while statement that calls inputCaloriesByDay() with argument from array
  while (daycount <= 6) {
    day = weekDays[daycount];
    totalCalories += inputCaloriesByDay(day)
    daycount += 1;
  }
  return totalCalories
}
```

Next, we can turn that while loop into a call to `.map()`. The `.map` method of an array just says "Hey, run through this array and for each item in the array, do something to it and return it"...so you could run through an array of numbers, add one to each number and return it. That would look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function(number) {
  return number+=1;
})
```

In our case though, we want to run through each week day in the "weekDays" array and call the `inputCaloriesByDay` method with that week day as the argument. We can do that like this:

```
var DAY = {
  MONDAY: 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY: 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY: 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY: 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY: 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY: 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY: 'SUNDAY',
};

function getTotalCalores() {
  //array for days of week (0-6)
  var weekDays = Object.values(DAY);

  var dayCalories = weekDays.map(function(day) {
    return inputCaloriesByDay(day);
  });

  return totalCalories
}
```

That's going to leave us with an array of numbers where each number is the calorie count for a day. So it's gone through our array of week days and given us a number for each day. We *could* loop through that once again and add things up with a `while` or a `for` loop...but it turns out that there's a better way still. We can use another method called `reduce`. Reduce (like map) runs through an array of things - they could be objects, numbers, strings or whatever and does something with them...but it then _reduce_s(see what I did there? ;)) them all down to a single value. In our case, we can run through our array of numbers and add them all together into one value. That looks like this:

```
var DAY = {
  MONDAY: 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY: 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY: 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY: 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY: 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY: 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY: 'SUNDAY',
};


function getTotalCalores() {
  //array for days of week (0-6)
  var weekDays = Object.values(DAY);

  var dayCalories = weekDays.map(function(day) {
    return inputCaloriesByDay(day);
  });

  return dayCalories.reduce(function(accumulator, value) {
    return accumulator += value;
  }, 0);
}
```

`accumulator` means the temporary variable we're holding all our stuff in until we're run and ready to return a value. In our case that's just a number that we keep adding to for every iteration of the loop. We initialize that value to `0` - which is the last param we pass into `.reduce`...

The only other thing left to do is clean things up a bit...like so:

It's generally recommended good practice to use `const` instead of `var` where possible to prevent variable re-assignment and scope bugs, so let's do that:

```
const DAY = {
  MONDAY: 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY: 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY: 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY: 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY: 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY: 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY: 'SUNDAY',
};


function getTotalCalores() {
  //array for days of week (0-6)
  const weekDays = Object.values(DAY);

  const dayCalories = weekDays.map(function(day) {
    return inputCaloriesByDay(day);
  });

  return dayCalories.reduce(function(accumulator, value) {
    return accumulator += value;
  }, 0);
}
```

Next, we can squish down those long-hand `function`s into JS [fat arrow](https://hackernoon.com/getting-to-grips-with-es6-arrow-functions-ebfa62c5c5d6) functions...

```
const DAY = {
  MONDAY: 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY: 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY: 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY: 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY: 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY: 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY: 'SUNDAY',
};


function getTotalCalores() {
  //array for days of week (0-6)
  const weekDays = Object.values(DAY);

  const dayCalories = weekDays.map((day) => inputCaloriesByDay(day));

  return dayCalories.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator += value, 0);
}
```

Then, we can actually just [chain our methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) together to clean things up even more...

```
const DAY = {
  MONDAY: 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY: 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY: 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY: 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY: 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY: 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY: 'SUNDAY',
};

function getTotalCalores() {
  return Object.values(DAY)
    .map((day) => inputCaloriesByDay(day))
    .reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator += value, 0);
}
```

---

### Solution:

Finally, we can also turn that `function getTotalCalories` into a fat arrow function too...

```
const DAY = {
  MONDAY: 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY: 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY: 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY: 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY: 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY: 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY: 'SUNDAY',
};


const getTotalCalores = () => Object.values(DAY)
    .map((day) => inputCaloriesByDay(day))
    .reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator += value, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did not mean this as an opinion question, I was more focused on extrapolating this to real world solutions.  With only seven days in the week, making seven variables is simple, but if this were pulling data from a much larger set (say, the program was designed with input and kept data for a year) changes things.  From you explanation, I think the answer is the array is good for the storage, but there is a more efficient way to pull the data that I have not learned yet (I've been doing this for about two weeks). What you laid out is great, it is a good place to start.

Comment: Ah, cool. That makes sense. In that case you could probably just replace my `Object.values` with your original array of week days.

The question sounded like a refactoring - a.k.a: "How can I refactor this to be more compact" kind of question. So rather than just dump the end solution and go "Have that", I figured it was important to explain step by step how I got there from your original code. Take care.

I would also add that using functional methods like that also allows you to slot things like `.filter` in there to pair down your results even more :)...if you need to